# Ignore 'AND', 'OR' constructions with query_string in elastic search and do literally search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

In elasticsearch it's possible to execute the following query:

```
GET /_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(apple) OR (banana)",
        }
      }
    }
```

This results in all documents having any field with the value 'apple' or 'banana'. I'm looking for a way to prevent the user from writing queries like "(apple) OR (banana)" in the search box. **This should be converted to a literal search for "(apple) OR (banana)" (so returning any document with a value set to "(apple) OR (banana)"). What's the best way to do this?**

*To give a bit more context: "query_string" was chosen to be able to perform 'contains' queries on entire documents using wildcards.*

Thank you in advance!

**[Edit]** To be a bit more clear:
Example:

- Doc 1: { "snack": "apple" }
- Doc 2: {"snack": "banana"}
- Doc 3: {"snack": "(apple) OR (banana)"}

If the user would search for **"(apple) OR (banana)"** this normally results in Doc 1 and Doc 2, but I would want it to match only with Doc 3.

**Solved thanks to @Bhavya and @TreffnonX:**
Summary: took @Bhavya solution, but wrapped my search string in extra double quotes:

```
    GET _search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "\"\\(apple\\) OR \\(banana\\)\""
        }
      }
}
```

or

```
 GET _search
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "\"(apple) OR (banana)\""
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. Can you please explain what do you mean by **should be converted to a literal search**?

Comment: @Bhavya Sorry :'D, I mean that searching for "(apple) OR (banana)" would return results for values having the exact value "(apple) OR (banana)" (so without interpretation of the query language). So the results wouln't contain values matching with either apple or banana. 

Example: 
- Doc 1: { "snack": "apple" }
- Doc 2: {"snack": "banana"}
- Doc 3: {"snack": "(apple) OR (banana)"}

Searching for "(apple) OR (banana)" normally results in Doc 1 and Doc 2, but I would want it to match only with Doc 3.

Comment: You want to escape the search input and only literally search for the entered character sequence? The following characters need to be escaped by a backslash `+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ `.

Comment: @TreffnonX I thought so too, but this results in an error: "Unrecognized character escape '(' (code 40)\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 4, column: 19]"

Comment: Most likely you are creating the json inside some other language. You probably need to escape the backslash itself as well: `"\\("` (e.g. in Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{ "snack": "apple" }

 {"snack": "banana"}

{"snack": "(apple) OR (banana)"}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\(apple\\) OR \\(banana\\)"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64352271",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 4.0350027,
        "_source": {
          "snack": "(apple) OR (banana)"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately  "\\(apple\\) OR \\(banana\\)" doesn't do the trick. I don't get back any results. Searching for "?apple*" does work (as in: the document with "(apple) OR (banana)" is returned, so I know it exists)

Comment: @Gybelle I tried it locally with `"query": "\\(apple\\) OR \\(banana\\)"`, and it is giving me the expected search result

Comment: solved my issue with your solution, but wrapping extra double quotes around \\(apple\\) OR \\(banana\\) . Thanks!